# sql - exclude null values

Tags: mysql, sql

How to remove those non-value columns?
This is my query:

```
SELECT CASE 
            WHEN region = 'CENTRAL'
               THEN 'Central' 
             WHEN region = 'EASTERN'
               THEN 'Eastern'   
               WHEN region = 'NORTHERN'
               THEN 'Northern' 
             WHEN region = 'SOUTHERN'
               THEN 'Southtern'               
  END as Peninsular , 
             case 
             WHEN region = 'BINTULU'
               THEN 'BINTULU' 
             WHEN region = 'KUCHING'
               THEN 'Kuching'   
               WHEN region = 'SIBU'
               THEN 'Sibu' 
   END as Sarawak,
            case 
             WHEN region = 'KOTA KINABALU'
               THEN 'KOTA KINABALU' 
             WHEN region = 'LAHAD DATU'
               THEN 'LAHAD DATU'  
               WHEN region = 'SANDAKAN'
               THEN 'SANDAKAN'
               WHEN region = 'TAWAU'
               THEN 'TAWAU'
   END as Sabah,
   region  
FROM locinvaisle
group by region
```

[image: Result of the query]

Comment: could you please post your schema and also add sample data in your question ?

Comment: What is your expected output?  I can't think of anything to do here.

Comment: I expect the output only show the filled columns, but it seems like some values are still there but hidden/null, as u can see in 'Region' row is the actual values

Comment: Every row you are showing has empty columns. And you are even creating these yourself. Region BINTULU for instance has no Sabah. So how do you want to suppress the non-filled column? Do you want to show a text like 'EMPTY' instead? Or don't you want to show the BINTULU row at all? Please show your expected result. (And please don't show images, but paste the table data as text instead.)

Answer (score 2):

If region is your key value then add

```
...
FROM locinvaisle
WHERE region IS NOT NULL
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE 
            WHEN region = 'CENTRAL'
               THEN 'Central' 
             WHEN region = 'EASTERN'
               THEN 'Eastern'   
               WHEN region = 'NORTHERN'
               THEN 'Northern' 
             WHEN region = 'SOUTHERN'
               THEN 'Southtern'               
  END as Peninsular , 
             case 
             WHEN region = 'BINTULU'
               THEN 'BINTULU' 
             WHEN region = 'KUCHING'
               THEN 'Kuching'   
               WHEN region = 'SIBU'
               THEN 'Sibu' 
   END as Sarawak,
            case 
             WHEN region = 'KOTA KINABALU'
               THEN 'KOTA KINABALU' 
             WHEN region = 'LAHAD DATU'
               THEN 'LAHAD DATU'  
               WHEN region = 'SANDAKAN'
               THEN 'SANDAKAN'
               WHEN region = 'TAWAU'
               THEN 'TAWAU'
   END as Sabah,
   region  
FROM locinvaisle
WHERE region is not null AND region != ''
group by region
```

Depending if region is simply empty or null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

Add this line

```
where region is not null AND region != ''
```

after the table name.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN region = 'CENTRAL' THEN 'Central' 
       WHEN region = 'EASTERN' THEN 'Eastern'   
       WHEN region = 'NORTHERN' THEN 'Northern' 
       WHEN region = 'SOUTHERN' THEN 'Southern'               
    END as Peninsular , 
    CASE
       WHEN region = 'BINTULU' THEN 'BINTULU' 
       WHEN region = 'KUCHING' THEN 'Kuching'   
       WHEN region = 'SIBU' THEN 'Sibu' 
    END as Sarawak,
    CASE
       WHEN region = 'KOTA KINABALU' THEN 'KOTA KINABALU' 
       WHEN region = 'LAHAD DATU' THEN 'LAHAD DATU'  
       WHEN region = 'SANDAKAN' THEN 'SANDAKAN'
       WHEN region = 'TAWAU' THEN 'TAWAU'
    END as Sabah,
    region  
FROM 
    locinvaisle 
WHERE
    region IS NOT NULL AND region != ''
GROUP BY
    region
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a conditions
...........

FROM locinvaisle where region != ''